# php error: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM"

Tags: php, compiler-errors

```
class Foo {
  public function bar($thing) {
    return $thing * 2;
  }
}

echo Foo::bar::(4);
```

The code above shows this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM

Could you tell me why? I am new to php. Thank you very much!

Comment: I believe the syntax should be: `echo Foo::bar(4);`

Answer (score 1):

To call a class method without an instance you need to make it static.
Also the last "::" are too much.

```
class Foo {
    public static function bar($thing) {
        return $thing * 2;
    }
}

echo Foo::bar(4);
```

Comment: Got it! Thank you very much!